# Windows updates change firewall settings, break server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

Last night a Windows update ran on our server running Windows Server 2008 R2 and this morning we couldn't RDP into the box or access the sites that it hosts. The hosting provider *could* RDP into it though. They disabled the firewall which fixed the issue, allowing us to RDP into it and bringing the sites back online.

This happens whenever we install a Windows update -- the server reboots and, because of changed firewall settings, is inaccessible to anyone but the hosting provider after it comes back on.

How do we prevent this? What's causing it to happen?

Comment: does the fix (turning the firewall off) last longer then 90 minutes?  If not it could be a gpo that renables the FW settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosting provider probably has a setup script on the machine that runs when it reboots.  I'd imagine this would configure things like the firewall.

It's probably something that should have been disabled before they gave you the machine, but it seems like it may not have.  Check all the places things can start up and see if there's anything there that looks suspicious.

Does the problem happen if you just reboot the machine normally?

Comment: I believe it will happen if we reboot it manually. This would make sense -- going to do some testing this weekend and then work with the hosting provider to fix it. Thanks!